# Blind programmer: designing an interface in Xcode without being able to visually position UI elements

Tags: xcode, interface, voiceover

I am fairly new to Mac and iOS programming, and have recently decided to get really serious about developing applications for both platforms. The first step I took was to register to the Mac and iOS developer programs, download Xcode and study a book about Objective-C. I spent the last 6 weeks familiarizing myself with Objective-C, its syntax, concepts and the Foundation framework, and was purely developing command line applications for those purposes.

Now, the next step seems to be Cocoa and developing applications that offer graphical UIs, which I'm now looking into. Now, here's an issue I am having with this: as I am completely blind, I cannot visually see the screen. Thus, I use VoiceOver, the screen reader built into OS X and iOS. Maybe some of you devs have heard of VoiceOver at some point, as Apple has specified a variety of accessibility guidelines that concern VoiceOver. On that note, thanks a lot to all of you who abide by those guidelines, your effort is greatly appreciated!!! :-)

As for Xcode, it actually works really well with VoiceOver (VO). Adding in new UI elements is also no big deal, I can just copy them from the library and paste them into the view. However, **I cannot drag them around and set them up in an appealing fashion**, or at least I haven't found any way of doing it just yet as I'm just starting out!

Now, I really would like to know if there is any 'textual' way of arranging UI elements. I know the inspector has a great variety of options, but I'm not sure yet if any of them would let me, say, change the coordinates of an UI element by hand. Also, I've read about the new constraints which help create a consistent layout, but at this point I'm not really familiar with how they can be used or if they would be at all helpful in my case.

Also, I do realize that producing an interface that is 100% appealing to a sighted end user may not be possible for me, as it's hard for me to decide on color selections or to design a logo. Thus, I would probably need to hire someone for those things. However, if it would be possible for me to just specify the layout roughly, that would already help me a lot!

Thanks for any ideas / suggestions :-)

Robin

Comment: @suspectus: When editing a question, please keep in mind that the back ticks are for `code`, not for every keyword (at least in my opinion).

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but you can set the coordinates of the UI elements in the "Size Inspector" tab of the inspector.

Comment: @Martin R - just spent a while looking in Meta for guidance about this . I suspect you are right. It seems to be common place amongst users to highlight liberally and I have been corrupted too.

Comment: The version editor shows (command - option - shift - return) an xml representation of graphical interface. I don't know if it allows you to edit/make changes. There is a **lot** of stuff it shows and might be a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @Yohst, The version editor *does* allow making changes, but editing raw XML that IB reads/writes is not something I would ever recommend. Using the Size inspector is the right approach here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a blind user myself but I've worked with VoiceOver so hopefully some of this will help. I'm making this a community answer so feel free to add tips from your own experience if you've worked with UI layout in Xcode with VoiceOver.

---

When editing UI in Xcode there is an Inspector where you can change the size and position of the views. The shortcut to get to the Size Inspector is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. The same shortcut works with VoiceOver.

You said that you were coding for both iOS and OS X. On iOS the y-axis starts in the top and points downward (so a higher y value means that the view is lower on the screen). This means that x and y specify the upper left corner of the view and the width and height extends to the right and down from there.

On OS X it's the opposite. The y-axis start at the bottom and a higher y value means that the view is higher on the screen. In both cases the x-axis goes from left to right. This means that x and y specifies the lower left corner and the width and height extends to the right an up.

Further, each view is positioned relative to their parent instead of absolute coordinates. This means that if you position a view at x=10 and y=30 and then position another view inside that at x=5 and y=10 it will have an absolute position on the screen that is x=15 and y=40.

If you can picture the layout in your head then you should be able to do it like this but it may still be hard to do.

---

#### Update

At the top of the hierarchy these coordinates relate to the size of the window. On iOS you have fixed sizes (320×480 for the iPhone and 1024×768 for the iPad). Depending on if the device is in landscape or portrait one of these is the width and the other is the heigh. You usually subtract 20 pixels from the height to account for the status bar. So the coordinate where y=0 would be directly below the status bar.

On OS X you can change the size of the window yourself. I will try and explain where to find it.

At the top level. Navigate to the "source code group" and interact with it. There you should find a "navigation bar group" and a "table" and a "scroll area". Interact with the table. In that table you should find a list of Placeholders and a list of Objects. One of the Objects will be the "Window". With the Window selected, all the inspectors will change properties of the Window. You can quickly jump to the Size Inspector by changing to any inspector and then back to the Size Inspector. For exaple type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. The first two elements in the Size Inspector should be the Width and Height of the Window.

Comment: Sorry, I think when I commented on your answer before I accidentally commented on the wrong answer, this site unfortunately is a Little confusing for a first-time screenreader user! :-( Well, Your instructions are really great, I just tested this before and it seems to be exactly what I wanted! Only question that remains is what do the coordinates relate to? I guess they relate to how large the window is in Terms of Pixels, but how do I figure that out?

Comment: If I could figure that out, then I could calculate where an element would have to go if, for example, I wanted to put it right in the middle of the window. Thanks a lot for your great help!

Comment: @Robin They relate to the size of the window. On iOS you have fixed sizes (320×480 for the iPhone and 1024×768 for the iPad). On OS X you can change the size yourself. I updated the answer to try and explain how to change the size of a Window in Xcode 4.6. The VoiceOver navigation isn't completely natural to me but I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion will inevitably go off-topic, but here are my ideas:

1. Consider specializing in something else. There are so many things a programmer can work on.  Many, if not most, programmers can enjoy long, successful careers without ever having to arrange any UI elements. Frankly, I don't think that this is particularly exciting, unless you have more of a designer mindset.
2. Alternatively, whatever tool you are using to arrange the elements, this layout is probably saved to some file, probably in some XML-like fashion. Find this file and edit it.
3. If you want to get really good at arranging UI elements, consider first hiring several people to do multiple arrangements for you. Then analyze the numbers and come up with some kind of formula that will be a good heuristic for such an arrangement. Or perhaps somebody has already come up with this kind of formula.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for the great Explanation!!! This got me in the right place so thank you very much for your advice! :-) Just one last question: what do the coordinates relate to? I assume it's Pixels that specify how large the window is, but can I somehow determine the window size? Because then this would be relatively simple, I could just think about where in the window I want a certain control to be, calculate the coordinates based on window size and then place it there, at least that's my theory for now!