# Is there a tutorial for coding a GUI without the inaccessible Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, accessibility, builder

I am totally blind and want to code for IOS and/or OS X. In Xcode 5.1, accessibility is improved, but the interface builder still seems unaccessible for voiceover users (like me).

With that in mind, is there a tutorial for coding OS X and iPhone apps without using interface builder in Xcode? Alternatively, is there a way to use interface builder with voiceover (without sight)? I would deffinately like to use gui tools if any exist, but if I have to hard code the thing, so be it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is couple of links that might be helpful. I will continue researching this question since it is amazingly intriguing. http://blog.austinlouden.com/post/47644085183/your-first-ios-app-100-programmatically

http://dennisdai.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-build-iphone-project-in-xcode-43.html

Comment: Here's  a similar question, its answer may be helpful to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638608/blind-programmer-designing-an-interface-in-xcode-without-being-able-to-visually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not listened to it but give the following podcast a listen. The description states that it covers interface builder basics.
http://maccessibility.net/2013/01/17/the-maccessibility-dev-podcast-1-using-xcode-with-voiceover/

Comment: Wow! This is the only tutorial I've ever seen that shows clearly how to use Interface Builder with Voiceover! Just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My sense of the matter is that you should simply code the interface.

First, autolayout makes this much more sensible than it has been in the past. The "visual" constraint language is really symbolic; made for you.

Second, the binding pane simply won't work for you. Bad design, I guess. But there we are. Use the API.

A number of sighted coders, including Brent Simmons (netnewswire, vesper) scarcely use interface builder. You'll be fine without it.

Comment: I've been writing iOS apps for over 5 years and have never used Interface Builder. It is definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider RubyMotion as an alternative.

[Austin Seraphin](http://behindthecurtain.us/about/) talks about using RubyMotion as a blind developer in this talk [MP3](http://goodvibes.zapto.org/curtain/2013-09-20_Nickel_City_Ruby.mp3) with slides [here](http://fr.slideshare.net/AdrianoMartino/ruby-motion-andiosaccessibility) at the #inspect2013 conference. I found the talk through a [blog posting](http://toamitkumar.com/blog/2013/04/09/impressions-at-inspect2013-rubymotion-conference/) that mentioned Austin's amazing presentation.

For pure XCode use, I tried experimenting with PaintCode but it was useless in Voice Over mode. You may find [Erica Sadun's](http://ericasadun.com/) book on Auto-Layout useful as she goes into detail on the code-based approach. The iBooks link to the second edition is [here](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/au/book/ios-auto-layout-demystified/id727646366?mt=11&ei=yUmEUr-8Fc3MkQXMqICoBw&usg=AFQjCNFC5O4bH3p6ztSbDG4AbpJBm5pxqg&sig2=lwk9rLfGXY180-EYBbyvGg&bvm=bv.56343320,d.dGI).

I am humbled by the effort that people like Austin and yourself put forth to overcome your obstacles and try to remember this whenever I'm irritated by the minor inconveniences in my life and software development. It seems fatuous to say thank you but I'd just like to offer my congratulations on what you've achieved so far.

Comment: Grate answer, I like the idea of interacting with my app while it runs. Unfortunately, I don't know ruby and ruby motion costs $200, no trials to experiment with. Worth investigating though.

Comment: Thank you for your congrats. One of the biggest obstacles to happy software use for me, is lack of accessibility. I feel so happy when I can just open an app and use it, out of the box. Thankfully, most developers label controls and keep their apps accessible. That means the world to blind users like me!